# Difference between @PathVariable, @RequestParam, and @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I understand what the `@PathVariable`, `@RequestParam` and `@RequestBody` does in Spring, but not clear on which scenarios we have to use them as they are used for extracting value from the URI. Why we have to send data like localhost:8080/getBooks/time and localhost:8080/getBooks?book=time.

Comment: Never use verb for endpoint, in your case you're using getBook/, better would be using books/ instead.(Following REST best practices). Refer: https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/#h-use-nouns-instead-of-verbs-in-endpoint-paths

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`@PathVariable` is for parts of the path (i.e. /person/{id})

`@RequestParam` is for the GET query parameters (i.e. /person?name="Bob").

`@RequestBody` is for the actual body of a request.

Answer (score 16):

Example 1:
`@RequestParam` is used mainly for filtering purposes
Lets say you want to get George Martin's book:
`GET localhost:8080/books?author=georgemartin`
Here we pass `author=georgemartin` as request parameter. This will supposedly get all of Martin's books, example game of thrones series.
This will be used mainly for GET operation.

Example 2:
`@PathVariable` is used mainly for getting individual objects or piece of data
Lets say you want to get a book by its id:
`GET localhost:8080/books/1`
Here we pass 1 as path variable. This will supposedly get the 1 book with id 1, example first part of game of thrones' book.
This will be used mainly for DELETE/GET operation.

Example 3:
`@RequestBody` is used mainly for saving object(s)(or piece of data)
Lets say you want to add a book:
`POST localhost:8080/books/`
With request body having following attributes:

```
{
  "author":"George Martin",
  "Book":"Game of thrones"
  ...
  ...
}
```

This will add a book to the db. This would be used mainly for PUT/POST operation.

Note: never use verb naming for endpoint, instead, use plural nouns. So books/ is ideal instead of getbooks/. 

Reference/Read more:
https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/#h-use-nouns-instead-of-verbs-in-endpoint-paths
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html

Comment: EDIT: we can use verb convention for endpoints like `/search`. But the idea is to follow one convention across

Answer (score 1):

@RequestBody used with POST Verb whereas
@RequestParam and @pathVariable used with GET Verb

@RequstParam  : It extract the value from query string
used for fitering,sorting and pagination
In Request Param the values can be encrypted
localhost:8080/getBooks?start=1&end=100

@pathVariable : It extract value from URI Path
In Path variable the value cannot be encoded
Its used get the data based on the value

Reference:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestparam-vs-pathvariable